# Java Client Serve Architecure

Tags: java, mysql, client-server

I want to build an E learning app using Java. The GUI will be made using JavaFX and for database I will use MySQL. So far application runs fine on localhost. But I want the application to be multi user. I m a little confused because I ve read different options like client/server and RMI. What would be the best approach in this case? For example, if the database is on another computer, and several clients will run the app (the app will contain both GUI part and database operations part via JDBC) is it ok? Or do I need to separate client part (like GUI) from actual database operations (Server part)? What about RMI? Does it make sense to use RMI in this case? 
In the database the app will store user credentials and user progress. I will grateful if someone could help me clarify this

Comment: Hi Robert, for an answer to your question it would be great to know a little bit more about your goal. Do the users e. g. download your e-learning app and work all alone (then maybe you could shipt the DB to every user), how do users get new content for the app? do you want to track the progress of users, can they collaborate (then maybe centralize the db). Have a look on thin/thick client architectures and independently on communication patterns like REST/RMI/(g)RPC
Best

Comment: Is it a requirement for the user to be able to work offline, unconnected to the network? Is the server to be installed on a local network? Or will the users be connecting over the internet?

Comment: This question is likely too broad for Stack Overflow. See a discussion site such as CodeRanch.com.

Comment: @BasilBourque no, the user will work exclusively online. The users will connect over the internet

Comment: Consider using [*Vaadin Flow*](http://www.Vaadin.com/) to build a web app in pure Java using widgets on a layout in a manner similar to JavaFX. You define your forms using your choice of straight Java code, an XML declarative language, or a visual editor. You deploy your .WAR file to any standard Jakarta Servlet container (web app server). At runtime, Vaadin generates the HTML, CSS, JavaScript necessary to render your user-interface on the client side in any common web browser.  So pure Java on the server, no Java on the client. That server-side Java code is connecting safely to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would NOT recommend exposing the DB to the Internet.
I would recommand implementing an REST-API for the Communication between DB and Client (JavaFX GUI). The big advantage is that you can control which operations can be executed against the DB and which not. I dont now about RIM btw.